# How to get the NetSuite account meta-data from the NetSuite API?

Tags: api, netsuite

I have an analytics app where people can plug their NetSuite account. Ideally, I would also retrieve some meta-data about the NetSuite account itself (ex: company name, etc) to make the analytics results more readable.

Does the [NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP API](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/schema/record/account.html) offers the possibility to retrieve meta-data about the NetSuite account itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get most of the company information using Configuration APIs

```
var companyinfo = nlapiLoadConfiguration('companyinformation');
var companyName = companyInfo.getFieldValue('companyname');
```

For a list of complete available fields please read "Preference Names and IDs"

EDIT:

Since, in SuiteTalk API, there is no specific API to fetch company information. I would recommend to write a RESTlet using above code and then access it via HTTPS in your Analytics application. If your application has to support multiple NetSuite account you may want to bundle your RESTlet.

Comment: Thanks. Is this information available through SuiteTalk?

Comment: also, the account link you are referring to is not a ns account, but, it is an account record from chart of accounts

Comment: Hi prasun, thanks, but I am a bit lost. I can't find the API spec this 'RESTlet' API. Is it publicly accessible like the SuiteTalk API? Btw, my code cannot run within SuiteScript.

Comment: No, you need to have access to a NetSuite account and code needs to be hosted within NetSuite

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needed to get the Company name, took me days to figure out so im sharing. You can use the token information endpoint defined here https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/chapter_157017286140.html

> Calling a token endpoint to obtain user information based on a token
> The tokeninfo endpoint returns information about a user based on the access token. The endpoint is https://{accountID}.restlets.api.netsuite.com/rest/tokeninfo, where  is a variable for the company’s account ID. A response to a GET request contains data in JSON format, including information such as: Company Name, Company ID (account ID), Role Name, Role ID, Entity ID

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite provides a Roles service that contains some very limited metadata about the account (Name and ID). See the Help Document titled "[Using the REST roles Service to Get User Accounts, Roles, and Domains](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2972111.html)".